# Dropdown List with PHP and jQuery Custom select menu

Tags: jquery, drop-down-menu

I want fill my dropdown list from my sql database with php.

I create two tables:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `categories` (
  `id` INT(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `category_name` VARCHAR(100) NOT NULL,
   PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB;

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `subcategories` (
  `id` INT(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `categoryID` INT(11) NOT NULL,
  `subcategory_name` VARCHAR(100) NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB;
```

Create a config.php file to store the database connection :

```
<?php

mysql_connect('localhost', 'root', '');
mysql_select_db('dependent_list');

?>
```

Create an index.php file :

```
<?php 
include('config.php'); 
$query_parent = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM categories") or die("Query failed: ".mysql_error());
?>
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>Dependent DropDown List</title>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {

    $("#parent_cat").change(function() {
        $(this).after('<div id="loader"><img src="img/loading.gif" alt="loading subcategory" /></div>');
        $.get('loadsubcat.php?parent_cat=' + $(this).val(), function(data) {
            $("#sub_cat").html(data);
            $('#loader').slideUp(200, function() {
                $(this).remove();
            });
        }); 
    });

});
</script>
</head>

<body>
<form method="get">
    <label for="category">Parent Category</label>
    <select name="parent_cat" id="parent_cat">
        <?php while($row = mysql_fetch_array($query_parent)): ?>
        <option value="<?php echo $row['id']; ?>"><?php echo $row['category_name']; ?></option>
        <?php endwhile; ?>
    </select>
    <br/><br/>

    <label>Sub Category</label>
    <select name="sub_cat" id="sub_cat"></select>
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

Now create a loadsubcat.php file :

```
<?php 
include('config.php');

$parent_cat = $_GET['parent_cat'];

$query = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM subcategories WHERE categoryID = {$parent_cat}");
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($query)) {
    echo "<option value='$row[id]'>$row[subcategory_name]</option>";
}

?>
```

Until now everything works fine.

But I want to use custom select menu from jquerymobile as on the link :
http://demos.jquerymobile.com/1.4.5/selectmenu-custom/

for that i change this code in index.php

```
<select name="parent_cat" id="parent_cat">
```

to :

```
<select name="parent_cat" id="parent_cat"  data-native-menu="false" class="filterable-select" data-iconpos="left">
```

and for sub cat from :

```
<select name="sub_cat" id="sub_cat"></select>
```

to :

```
<select name="sub_cat" id="sub_cat"  data-native-menu="false" class="filterable-select" data-iconpos="left">
```

The select menu items appear in popup and not work not loade the data from database.

Any Help?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are creating select boxes by calling db call and it generates options dynamically. You need to call `.selectmenu();` on select boxes after creating options to it. try below code -

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    //apply custom select on parent category
    $("#parent_cat").selectmenu();

    $("#parent_cat").change(function() {
        $(this).after('<div id="loader"><img src="img/loading.gif" alt="loading subcategory" /></div>');
        $.get('loadsubcat.php?parent_cat=' + $(this).val(), function(data) {
            $("#sub_cat").html(data);
            //apply custom select on sub category
            $("#sub_cat").selectmenu();

            $('#loader').slideUp(200, function() {
                $(this).remove();
            });
        }); 
    });
});
```

**Note** -  Above solution is assuming that you have already included jquery mobile library required for custom select.

Comment: Thank you very much for your help.
The first list works well with your code but the second show empty
the sub_cat is empty.
Of course i add included jquery:

 <script type="text/javascript" src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.8.3.js"></script>

Comment: check if `data` is not empty for `$("#sub_cat").html(data);`, see if you can get normal options list without using selectMenu().

Comment: Of course non-empty.

if i remove data-native-menu="false" from <select it work fine.

I think the problem is caused becuse the menu open in popup this url :http://localhost/list/#&ui-state=dialog


but the first menu work fine.

The problem here Photos

http://im65.gulfup.com/2TwHzU.png

http://im65.gulfup.com/qWMcR0.png

Comment: I am not able to open the screen shot  send by you. Can you please explain me the problem.

Comment: when i use html like this is work fine:
`<select name="parent_cat" id="parent_cat">`
`<select name="sub_cat" id="parent_cat">`
but when i use like this the first menu(parent_cat) it's work but the second menu(sub_cat) not work i show is empty:
`<select name="parent_cat" id="parent_cat" data-native-menu="false" class="filterable-select" data-iconpos="left"></select>` 
`<select name="sub_cat" id="sub_cat" data-native-menu="false" class="filterable-select" data-iconpos="left"></select> `

Comment: can you reproduce this on jsfiddle link and pass it to me